# Woocommerce, Checkout, Order -> Advanced Custom Field: set value from HTML selector

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

How do I set the value of a custom field on an order, upon checkout submit, to a selected value in an HTML component?

I've implemented a custom HTML component, inside the checkout form, whose selected value I want to insert in a custom field on my orders. But I can't seem to figure out how to hook these things up.
I've arrived at somthing like:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['special_delivery'] = 'The value from HTML';
     return $fields;
}
```

But I'm not even sure that's the right way to go.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Using `woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form` allows you to add custom fields to your checkout form. You also need to save the field in the order meta using `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`.

In the following code there is a custom text field used for saving VAT ID. Feel free to get rid of the "mrank" prefixes. Also rename the field as you need it.

It will show you how to add a field and to save in order meta.

```
/**
* VAT Number in WooCommerce Checkout
*/
function mrank_vat_field( $checkout ) {

      echo '<div id="mrank_vat_field">';
   
      woocommerce_form_field( 'vat_number', array(
            'type'          => 'text',
            'class'         => array( 'vat-number-field form-row-wide') ,
            'label'         => __( 'VAT-ID' ),
            'placeholder'   => __( 'Enter number' ),
            'description' => __( 'Please enter your VAT-ID' ),
            'required'    => true,
      ), $checkout->get_value( 'vat_number' ));
    
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'mrank_vat_field' );


/**
* Save VAT Number in the order meta
*/
function mrank_checkout_vat_number_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['vat_number'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_vat_number', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['vat_number'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'mrank_checkout_vat_number_update_order_meta' );
```

Comment: I've tried implementing what you described. It doesn't seem to work. But it definitely seems like the correct way to do things. I think the thing that breaks is the part where I'd want to store the value in an Advanced Custom Field. What your example does is using more common metafields, isn't it? How would I push that value into a custom field?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use an Advanced Custom Fields instead of a meta field in the order? I don't see a reason why this would make a differnece. But surely you can below the `update_post_meta( ...) ` just add the function to update your ACF-field: `update_field( 'field_key', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['vat_number'], $order_id );`

Comment: No particularly good reason, aside from it being set up that way :D I still can't get it to work. I feel like I'm doing exactly what you're describing. I've updated the initial post with what my code is, if you could see at what I'm doing wrong that would be awesome! :)

Comment: Where did you put this code? Inside of a custom plugin, or functions.php, or somewhere else? If you don't need to use ACF, please just use my "update_post_meta" because ther e will be a new meta field in your order, which is fine. No need for ACF ;)

Comment: I'm putting this inside form-billing.php :o

Comment: Try to put it in a custom plugin or in the functions.php of your theme. then go to the checkout page and check if there is the new field displayed.

Comment: It's being inserted correctly on the page. But it's not setting the value at all. I've tried putting it elsewhere. Seems better to put it in functions.php than form-billing, for sure :)
Is it because it's a select field, maybe?

Comment: Yes, this is something different. When you look at my code, it is for a text field. Maybe this helps you to rewrite the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480587/woocommerce-checkout-custom-select-field/40480684